# Unable to catch connectivity errors between linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

For some reason I cannot catch connectivity related errors only in a specific server.

There is a communication between 2 SQL-Servers through linked server. Sometimes the connection is bad and the the result is the following error:

*TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.*

I Have try-catch to handle this issue and everything works fine since the severity is not above 20.

```
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_someSP]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE(),ERROR_NUMBER(),ERROR_SEVERITY(),ERROR_PROCEDURE()
--NEVER GOES HERE!!!
END CATCH
```

the procedure will cause the following error:

> OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" returned message
>   "Protocol error in TDS stream". OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked
>   server "(null)" returned message "Communication link failure". Msg 64,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 0 TCP Provider: The specified network name is
>   no longer available. OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server
>   "(null)" returned message "Query timeout expired".

I tested the linked Server and works fine (I even recreated the Linked Server)

```
Linked Server Configuration:

@optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'

@optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'

@optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'

@optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'

@optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'

@optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'

@optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'

@optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'100'

@optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null

@optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'

@optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'100'

@optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'

@optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

SQL Server: 2008 R2 Standard Edition (64-bit)

I cannot understand why I cannot catch the following error.

EDIT: The problem lies beyond the execution of the Stored Procedure. Even if I execute something like this:

```
EXEC ('Select * from SomeTable') at LinkedServer
```

Sometimes (Less than 0.1% of the cases) I will get the mentioned error.
I am trying to find some kind of pattern but so far no luck. Also, I searched if there is some kind of network configuration that might be killing the queries but the result was negative.

Comment: Check [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36178/44324). It is a compile time error.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal thank you for your fast response and your edit. I have already read this question but I could not figure a way to help me.

Comment: Did you try executing the stored procedure using dynamic SQL?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I just tried Dynamic Query but the result was the same.

Comment: Please update your question with the code of the dynamic executionof sp that, as you say, produce uncathable error

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos Did you solve it?

Comment: @sepupic There is nothing wrong with the code since it works in many servers. Even if execute a Select * from a table located into a Linked Server might proc the error. The result set of Select * does not affect the outcome.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Unfortunately no. I just made sure there was no network interference.

Comment: @EmmanouilKaramalegos Did you try the second version from my answer? The problem in your question was that the error did not get caught.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = 'EXEC [YourDatabase].[dbo].[sp_someSP]';   
    EXEC (@sql) AT [YourServer];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

Or one level up like that:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000) = 
       'EXEC (''EXEC [YourDatabase].[dbo].[sp_SomeSP] 
       ''''Parameter1'''', ''''Parameter2'''''') AT [YourLinkedServer]';
    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql); 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36195/44324), it seems that the cause is a compile time error.